# Apple inapp Purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am new to in app purchase concept of apple. I am developing an application which displays videos from a server. All videos are charged, to pay for a particular video I am thinking of implementing the in app purchase(I dont know whether this can be done any other way).

This is how I am trying to implement it. When user pays for a video he will get the url for that particular video and he can then download that video and watch it. here is my doubt do I need to add all the video urls to app store before it can be made available for in app purchase?

Is there any way that the urls are kept on my server and once payment confirmation is obtained I can make that url visible to the user?

I have goe through these tutorials [Tutorial1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases) and [Tutorial2](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/)

Can some one please help me?
How can I do this properly in ios?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, you can let user select a video, and when you get `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased`, provide him a link from your server.
After that, just `finishTransaction`.
You can also update a list of videos dynamicly from your server before showing to the user.